# CentOS 5 in VirtualBox 4.1 shows 0 as disk free space

Tags: linux, centos, hard-drive, virtualbox, disk-space-utilization

I just installed a brand new centos 5.8 64bit on virtualbox 4.1.10 with guest additions installed

I gave it a dynamically allocated 8gb hard drive. It is currently using only 3.9gb of that.
However, it seems to think that 3.9 gb is all that is has got and free space is shown as 0.

This means i am unable to install any updates or any other applications.

How do i make linux see the full 8gb?

```
[pdeva@localhost ~]$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                  3.9G  3.6G   62M  99% /
/dev/sda1              99M   13M   81M  14% /boot
tmpfs                 4.2G     0  4.2G   0% /dev/shm
unpack                239G  228G   11G  96% /media/sf_unpack
/dev/hdc               49M   49M     0 100% /media/VBOXADDITIONS_4.1.10_76836
```

[image]
[image]

```
    [root@localhost pdeva]# /usr/sbin/pvdisplay 
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               VolGroup00
  PV Size               7.90 GB / not usable 23.41 MB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size (KByte)       32768
  Total PE              252
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          252
  PV UUID               8frMVE-VDj5-Nuhm-PkJ7-9aPT-BvSa-v8WlpP

[root@localhost pdeva]# /usr/sbin/vgdisplay 
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               VolGroup00
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               7.88 GB
  PE Size               32.00 MB
  Total PE              252
  Alloc PE / Size       252 / 7.88 GB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               MPuRl0-ikuh-fxoM-P62x-WBBA-jqCB-94s9V9

[root@localhost pdeva]# /usr/sbin/lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
  VG Name                VolGroup00
  LV UUID                dzHm7O-Wj0K-7I30-P6Bs-lpqh-9F9y-bOs2em
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                3.97 GB
  Current LE             127
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01
  VG Name                VolGroup00
  LV UUID                2iLTuY-yw9h-eQMD-LaVs-8ro1-QGBk-J7xk5P
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                3.91 GB
  Current LE             125
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1
```

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen.

Comment: added output of df

Comment: And now we need `pvdisplay`, `vgdisplay`, and `lvdisplay`.

Comment: added everything now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the rest of the space is being used by another LV. Mount it somewhere, inspect the contents, and see if you can get rid of the second LV in order to make more room for the first.

Comment: More specifically, you have a `/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01` which isn't mounted anywhere (`/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00` is your `/` and is full). Good catch @ignacio. I was staring at the free extents = 0 wondering what was happening...

Comment: `LogVol01` is going to be swap.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem. I needed to remove swap from the LogVol01 (`swapoff -v /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01`), then removed this volume, rebooted and extended the space of LogVol00 mounted as /.